# What's the default password for postgreSQL installed by Gitlab Omibus version?

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab

I installed Omnibus Gitlab using the docker image of gitlab-ce. Now my question is what's the default password for the embedded PostgreSQL database password?

I checked the Dockerfile and some scripts along with it from https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab, but could not find any clue.

Comment: Can you tell me what are getting once you open the URL in browser. As per the documentation, for the very first time if you open the gitlab it asks you to set password.

https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html#after-starting-a-container

Comment: Browsing on web is fine. What I asked actually is about how to setup specific user/password for PostgreSQL and how to access it afterwards to dome database operations.

Comment: kinda hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57992992/how-to-access-login-postgres-in-gitlab-omnibus-docker-container-or-from-remote-t/58479183?noredirect=1#comment103291827_58479183