# How to access/login postgres in gitlab omnibus docker container or from remote terminal?

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab

The **Omnibus** version of Gitlab by default are using `postgresql['enable'] = true`, this seems that the postgresql can not be accessed by normal `psql` command, even in the Omnibus Gitlab container itself.

So is this true? If not how can I access this embedded postgresql from remote terminal?

This question is really what I want to do and it relates to my another post [What's the default password for postgreSQL installed by Gitlab Omibus version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57986304/whats-the-default-password-for-postgresql-installed-by-gitlab-omibus-version)

Answer (score 0):

If it is omnibus and you are using bundled postgres then you can use `gitlab-rails dbconsole` for accessing the database.

So you can try something like this `docker exec -it CONTAINERID bash` and then you can simply run `gitlab-rails dbconsole`.

Do let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes, I know this ominbus is kinda bundle, and ```gitlab-rails dbconsole```, ```gitlab-psql -d gitlabhq_production``` all works to login PostgreSQL console inside the omnibus container. But I still can not figure out how to remotely access this PostgreSQL and use/read it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you mean by remotely?

Comment: Just like using any Mysql Clinent, for instance, MYSQL Workbench or Navicat to login mysql, I want to login the database of this gitlab by using DBeaver, which is a database client for PostgreSQL.

Comment: For that you need to check your `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file for the configuration and you can use those settings for connecting the database.

Answer (score 0):

As the official document explained but not that specific and clear, https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/database.html#configure-postgresql-block, 
to expose the Postgresql from Gitlab Omnibus version。

`postgresql['trust_auth_cidr_addresses']` and `postgresql['listen_address']` are important and have to specified together, whereas this details not that much put on the documentation. Just tweak these two carefully then you can telnet PostgreSQL or login it remotely by using DBeaver as a sql client.